# Print React component on every page

Tags: reactjs, printing, react-to-print

I'm using the react-to-print library but asking more generally - if I have a sidebar React component that I want to be printed on every page, is this possible? Kind of like a header/footer but a React component instead, that doesn't necessarily appear on the top or bottom of the page